# What kinds of manifolds admit non-vanishing vector fields defining convergent congruences?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, manifolds, euler-characteristics

One of the corollaries of the Poincaré–Hopf index theorem is that a closed, connected manifold $M$ admits non-vanishing vector fields iff its Euler characteristic is zero; i.e. $\chi(M) = 0$.

I am interested in finding out how one can strengthen this result, in terms of additional constraints on $M$, if we further restrict the "allowed" vector fields to ones with convergent [congruences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_%28manifolds%29). To clarify this, let's say a vector field defines a convergent congruence if all its integral curves are mutually convergent to one another in an asymptotic sense. [1]

I would appreciate suggestions, ideas or pointers to any relevant work.

[1] I can fix an exact criterion for defining asymptotic convergence of integral curves, if need be.

*Edit:* One simple example to consider is a torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Usual examples for non-vanishing vector fields on tori do not define convergent congruences; i.e. their integral curves do not converge asymptotically. I tried to construct one that does, but I haven't been successful so far.

Comment: A smooth (resp. geodesic) congruence is essentially the same thing as a non-vanishing (resp. Killing) vector field; do I understand correctly?

Comment: @Qfwfq: That's correct.